# What is wrong in the below query : Query using CTE showing 0 output while using subqueries showing intended output

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, common-table-expression

```
with emp as
(
    select employee_id, salary from employees where employee_id = 108 
)
select first_name, last_name, employees.salary, emp.salary from employees
left join emp
on emp.employee_id = employees.employee_id
where employees.salary > emp.salary
order by employees.salary desc;
```

I am trying to create an equivalent CTE for below query using the employees table

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name
  FROM employees
  WHERE salary > (SELECT salary
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE employee_id = 108);
```

Here is the snap of the table

[image]

Comment: Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `on emp.employee_id = employees.employee_id
where employees.salary > emp.salary` will never be true (at least as long as employee_id is unique/pk.)

Comment: q1 only compares the salary for 108 with 108, q2 compares everyone with 108.

Comment: @jarih : How to correct this any idea, seems like obvious solution but it is not

Comment: @jarih changed the join from right to left...

Comment: Remove `emp.employee_id = employees.employee_id` to compare this specific eployee to all employees

Answer (score 0):

The bellow query return just on record. The employee 108

```
with emp as
(
    select employee_id, salary from employees where employee_id = 108 
)
```

In the next query you do a left join employees left join emp

```
select 
    first_name, last_name, employees.salary, emp.salary 
from 
    employees left join emp
      on emp.employee_id = employees.employee_id
where 
    employees.salary > emp.salary
order by 
    employees.salary desc;
```

and so result without where "employees.salary > emp.salary" will be

```
Steven, King, 24'000, null
Neena, Kochlhar, 17'000, null,
...
Nancy, Greenberg, 12'000, 12'000
...
...
```

"12'000 > null" not work

You can try

```
with emp as
(
    select employee_id, salary from employees where employee_id = 108 
)
select
    first_name, last_name, employees.salary, emp.salary 
from 
    employees inner join emp
     on (employees.salary > emp.salary)
order by 
    employees.salary desc;
```